# After adding a ScrollView, the the app title is no longer displayed

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi in the below code i have a login layout in that contains email id and password are the attributes.

Now want to display my layout in landscape mode.because of that i just added scrollview.
Now my problem is after adding the scrollview to my layout "LOGIN" title not showing .

can any one please help me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#1c1c1c">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbarRel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@color/color_toolbar">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/login"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/heading_font_size"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#1c1c1c"
        android:fillViewport="false">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbarRel"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_email"
            style="@style/common_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/textfield_outer_box"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/img_email_icon"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/img_email_icon"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Email Id"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_pwd"
            style="@style/common_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/homogeneous_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/textfield_outer_box"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/img_password_icon"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/img_password_icon"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_login"
            style="@style/style_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/heterogenous_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/login_button"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/button_topbottom_padding"
            android:text="@string/get_started" />

   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/homogeneous_margin">

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Forgot Password?"
           android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
           android:gravity="center_vertical"
           android:textSize="18sp"
           android:textColor="@android:color/white"
           android:id="@+id/txt_forgot_password"/>
       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/text_create_account"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/homogeneous_margin"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:text="Create Account"
           android:textColor="@android:color/white"
           android:textSize="18sp" />
   </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/common_text"
        android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
        android:text="or sign with"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <!--<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton-->
            <!--android:id="@+id/login_button"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="0dp"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"-->
            <!--android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"-->
            <!--android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"-->
            <!--android:layout_margin="4dp"-->
            <!--android:layout_paddinBottom="12dp"-->
            <!--android:layout_paddingTop="12dp"-->
            <!--android:gravity="center"-->
            <!--android:layout_weight="1"-->
            <!--/>-->
        <!--<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton-->
            <!--android:id="@+id/signin_button"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="0dp"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_centerInParent="true"-->
            <!--android:layout_weight="1"/>-->


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your title is not displaying because the height of your `ScrollView` is `match_parent`

So your  `RelativeLayout` is hiding behind `ScrollView`

Just  add **`android:layout_below="@id/toolbarRel"`** in your **`ScrollView`**

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#1c1c1c">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbarRel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@color/color_toolbar">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/login"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/heading_font_size"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbarRel"
        android:background="#1c1c1c"
        android:fillViewport="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbarRel"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_email"
                style="@style/common_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/textfield_outer_box"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/img_email_icon"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/img_email_icon"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Email Id"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_pwd"
                style="@style/common_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/homogeneous_margin"
                android:background="@drawable/textfield_outer_box"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/img_password_icon"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/img_password_icon"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_login"
                style="@style/style_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/heterogenous_margin"
                android:background="@drawable/login_button"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/button_topbottom_padding"
                android:text="@string/get_started" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/homogeneous_margin">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_forgot_password"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Forgot Password?"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_create_account"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/homogeneous_margin"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Create Account"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                style="@style/common_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
                android:text="or sign with"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <!--<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/login_button"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="0dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"-->
        <!--android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_margin="4dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_paddinBottom="12dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_paddingTop="12dp"-->
        <!--android:gravity="center"-->
        <!--android:layout_weight="1"-->
        <!--/>-->
        <!--<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/signin_button"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="0dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:layout_centerInParent="true"-->
        <!--android:layout_weight="1"/>-->


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**UPDATE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#1c1c1c">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbarRel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Login"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbarRel"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#1c1c1c"
        android:fillViewport="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_email"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Email Id"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_pwd"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_login"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="get_started" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_forgot_password"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Forgot Password?"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_create_account"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Create Account"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
                android:text="or sign with"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:weightSum="2">


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: forgot password and create account those two textview's are not showing

Comment: what are the changes you did in update.can you please let me know

Comment: @jyocha added `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` in `Scrolview` and removed unused property

Comment: @jyocha please update your question with your current tried code and please add some scrennshot of current problem because for me above code is working fine thanks

Comment: @jyocha can u share any image of your required output